# Eigenfunction of a free particle going in the x direction quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics

When we talk about a free particle we have the Hamiltonian $H=\frac{p^2}{2m}$ and the TISE $\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\psi''(x)=E\psi(x)$ and, saying $k=\frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}$, we have two particular solutions $\psi(x)=Ae^{\pm ikx}$ and since the differential equation is linear the more general solution $\psi(x)=Ae^{ikx}+Be^{-ikx}$. This solution represents the particle that is moving in both directions, $x$ direction and the opposite direction.

**Why do we say that the eigenfunction that represents the particle moving towards the $x$ axis is $e^{ikx}$ and not $e^{-ikx}$?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you solve the time-*dependent* Schrodinger equation via separation of variables, we assume a wave function of the form
$$
\Psi(x,t) = e^{-iEt/\hbar}\psi(x)\,.
$$
For the special case of a free particle, this becomes
$$
\Psi(x,t) = e^{-i\omega_kt}e^{ikx}\,,
$$
where $\omega_k=\hbar k^2/2m$. Rewriting this as
$$
\Psi(x,t) = e^{i(kx-\omega_kt)}= e^{ik(x-vt)}\,,
$$
where $v=\omega_k/k$, we can see that, when $k$ is positive, this exactly corresponds to a right-moving wave, because replacing $x$ by $x-vt$ (with $v$ positive) is (mathematically speaking) a shift of $e^{ikx}$ to the right by $vt$, and this shift increases linearly with time as $vt$.

Comment: I don't understand what is $v$?

Comment: It's the phase velocity.  In other words, it's the speed at which the "shape" $e^{ikx}$ is moving.  That's implicit in the last part of the post.

Comment: So it's the phase velocity.